# Arial Narrow font issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, cross-browser

I am having a font issue with Arial Narrow. Because of this project, I **must** use `Arial Narrow`.

My only problem is, the font doesn't look the same in chrome as it does in firefox or safari.

Could anyone help me fix the problem? Or is it just the way the browser renders the font and there is nothing I can do?

**Firefox or Safari**
[image: firefox or chrome]

**Chrome**
[image]

```
.content { font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
```

[jsfiddle to see what I see.](http://jsfiddle.net/qc7m3/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't drive yourself nuts.  Convince yourself right now that it's never, ever going to be perfect.  It's not going to be the same between different browsers, nor is it necessarily going to be the same on the same browser on different operating systems (i.e. Firefox on Windows 7 vs Firefox on Windows 8 vs Firefox on Ubuntu vs Firefox on Mac vs Firefox on Android).  End-users are very quick to fixate on stuff like this ... they need educating, it's way over most of their heads.

The font selection is always subject to the browser and also the underlying font engine in the operating system.  There's really no clean way around it unless you are rendering the font yourself somehow and pushing vector or bitmap graphics into the browser.

For your single-line conundrum, consider using the ellipsis features of CSS.

http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html

Answer (score 3):

> My only problem is, the font doesn't look the same in chrome as it does in firefox or safari

That's just how the web is.

Consider yourself as someone who is suggesting the typography--but not dictating it. You're suggesting that a certain font be used at a certain size.

Beyond that, though, other factors come in to play...

- how does this particular browser render fonts?
- how does this particular OS render fonts?
- does it obey the kerning pairs?
- does it implement font smoothing?
- how does it implement font smoothing?
- what is the browser default sizes?
- did the user change the default sizes?
- did the user zoom in perhaps?
- or zoom out?
- or resize the browser?
- or open on a different device?
- etc.

> Or is it just the way the browser renders the font and there is nothing I can do?

Well...you probably COULD do something...maybe run javascript to measure the line widths and then re-calculate the font size to adjust the width or letter-spacing but in the end, it's all going to be a lot of extra code that may or may not actually 'fix' anything, may make things worse, and is really fighting the nature of how type works on the web.

Comment: Thanks @DA. It puts it into perspective. Sometimes I need text to fit on one line. And then when it doesn't it get's frusturating.